# How to save pdf in folder, with node.js

Tags: node.js, multer

Currently I save images in a folder using node.js. But now I need to save pdf documents. What adjustments should I make so that it accepts pdf documents and saves it in another folder.

This is my code to save images :

```
const multer = require('multer');
var uuid = require('uuid');
const path = require('path');
uuid=uuid.v4();
console.log(uuid);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, 'public/img/uploads'),
    filename: (req, file, cb, filename) => {

        cb(null, uuid() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
}) 
app.use(multer({storage}).single('image'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Are you facing any difficulties in saving PDF as I can see it should save the file. There is not filter for files here. If there is an error coming in while doing this you can add this to the question.

Comment: Apoorva Chikara If you correctly save images and also pdf files. But I would like to separate the image and pdf files into different folders.

Comment: does this helps?

Answer (score 0):

As you provided the above code works fine for the Images you can make change to the destination folder for pdf.

```
const imageFolderPath = 'public/img/uploads';
const pdfFolderPath = 'public/pdf/uploads';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb ) => {
        if (file.fieldname === 'img') { // check the fieldname
            cb(null, imageFolderPath);
        }
        else {
            cb(null, pdfFolderPath);
        }
     },
    filename: (req, file, cb, filename) => {
        cb(null, uuid() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
})
```

Checking the field name is important to change the path. You can make your logic in the destination method.

Note: make sure the path exists for the pdf folder before uploading.